# Finding the original row heights and col widths from merged cells

Tags: algorithm

I have some table that was produced by a framework and I have the sizes and coordinates of the cells. However, I now need to export this to another format, and this particular format does not have per-cell sizing, it only has sizing for rows and cols.

For instance I have this 3 by 6 table, with lots of merged cells:

- [0] {CellSize(0,0): w:8.5 h:7.111111}
- [1] {CellSize(0,1): w:48.5 h:3.888889}
- [2] {CellSize(1,0): w:26.83333 h:3.222222}
- [3] {CellSize(1,1): w:4.166667 h:3.222222}
- [4] {CellSize(1,2): w:4.416667 h:3.222222}
- [5] {CellSize(1,3): w:8.5 h:3.222222}
- [6] {CellSize(1,4): w:4.583333 h:3.222222}
- [7] {CellSize(2,0): w:8.5 h:3.222222}
- [8] {CellSize(2,1): w:26.83333 h:3.222222}
- [9] {CellSize(2,2): w:4.166667 h:3.222222}
- [10] {CellSize(2,3): w:4.416667 h:3.222222}
- [11] {CellSize(2,4): w:8.5 h:3.222222}
- [12] {CellSize(2,5): w:4.583333 h:3.222222}

What I would like to end up with are two arrays:

```
  rowHeights = [3.888889, 3.222222, 3.222222]
  colWidths = [8.5, 26.83333, 4.166667, 4.416667, 8.5, 4.583333]
```

My initial attempt is not working...

```
  //rows
  float[] rowSize = new float[table.RowsNumber];
  for (int i = 0; i < table.RowsNumber; i++)
    rowSize[i] = float.MaxValue;
  foreach (var cellSize in cellSizes)
    if (cellSize.height < rowSize[cellSize.row])
       rowSize[cellSize.row] = cellSize.height;

  //cols
  float[] colSize = new float[table.ColumnsNumber];
    for (int i = 0; i < table.ColumnsNumber; i++)
      colSize[i] = float.MaxValue;
  foreach (var cellSize in cellSizes)
    if (cellSize.width < colSize[cellSize.column])
      colSize[cellSize.column] = cellSize.width;
```

Anyone have a better idea?

edit:

I managed to find the rowspan and cellspan of the original table, and with that do this:

```
  float[] rowSize = new float[table.RowsNumber];
  foreach (var cellSize in cellSizes)
    if (cellSize.rowspan == 1)
      rowSize[cellSize.row] = cellSize.height;

  float[] colSize = new float[table.ColumnsNumber];
  foreach (var cellSize in cellSizes)
    if (cellSize.colspan == 1)
      colSize[cellSize.column] = cellSize.width;
```

That will give the correct numbers for the table above, and the rest of few test cases, but I am fairly certain that it doesn't work in all cases.

Comment: Is performance an issue?

Comment: not really. The amount of cells rarely exceed the above, perhaps twice as many.

Comment: So I guess your approach is Ok. Perhaps you may drop a loop testing simultaneously for cols and rows, but the code get slightly more convoluted, and if performance is not an issue, easy of maintenance always is.

Comment: Except it doesnt give the right answer... It incorrectly makes col 0 the same size as col 1 due to the merged cells

Comment: Oh, Sorry. I didn't check the numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was somewhat harder than I expected...

The only way I could come up with is make a 2 dimensional grid and then calculate the correct positions for the cells.

```
  Diagram.CellSize[,] correctPositions = new Diagram.CellSize[table.RowsNumber,table.ColumnsNumber];
  int rowoffset = 0;
  int currow = -1;
  //Needs to be processed in order, or the algorithm wont work
  foreach (var cellSize in cellSizes.OrderBy(c => c.row).ThenBy(c => c.column).ToList())
  {
     if (currow != cellSize.row)
     {
        rowoffset = 0;
        currow = cellSize.row;
     }
     //find out if the cell above us is actually rowspanned
     int rowabove = cellSize.row - 1;
     if (rowabove >= 0 && correctPositions[rowabove, cellSize.column + rowoffset].rowspan > 1)
     {
        correctPositions[cellSize.row, cellSize.column + rowoffset] =
           new Diagram.CellSize
              {
                 row = -1,
                 //keep track of the rowspan, so we just need to look 1 cell up
                 rowspan = correctPositions[rowabove, cellSize.column + rowoffset].rowspan - 1
              };
        rowoffset++;
     }

     //then set this cell
     correctPositions[cellSize.row, cellSize.column + rowoffset] = cellSize;
     for (int i = 1; i < cellSize.colspan; i++)
     {
        //adjust the current rowspan
        rowoffset++;
        correctPositions[cellSize.row, cellSize.column + rowoffset] =
           new Diagram.CellSize
              {
                 row = -1,
                 //keep track of the rowspan, if a cell has both rowspan and cell span
                 rowspan = cellSize.rowspan
              };
     }
  }
```

And now I can process using the original positions...

```
  //rows, find the first col in each row that is not merged and not spanned
  for (int i = 0; i < table.RowsNumber; i++)
  {
     for (int j = 0; j < table.ColumnsNumber; j++)
     {
        var cell = correctPositions[i, j];
        if (cell.row == -1 || cell.rowspan > 1)
           continue;
        table.SetRowHeight(i, (int) ((cell.height*ppSlideHeight)/100));
        break;
     }
  }
  //cols, find the first row in each col that is not merged and not spanned
  for (int j = 0; j < table.ColumnsNumber; j++)
  {
     for (int i = 0; i < table.RowsNumber; i++)
     {
        var cell = correctPositions[i, j];
        if (cell.row == -1 || cell.colspan > 1)
           continue;
        table.SetColumnWidth(j, (int) ((cell.width*ppSlideWidth)/100));
        break;
     }
  }
```

It wont work when all cells in a row are rowspanned away, or colspanned away (e.g. a table with 2 cols where both cols have a rowspan of 2)

Answer (score 0):

If i understood your question correctly

```
you don't need to initilize the respective arrays

List<float> rowSize = new List<float>();


for( int i =0 ; i <= cellSizes.Length-1 ;i++)
    {

       if (cellSize[i+1].height <= cellSize[i].height)
              rowSize.Add(cellSize[i+1].height);
       else
           rowSize.Add(cellSize[i].height);
    }
```

similar for columns